# Thermopride OL5-85 oil furnace no longer works

Tags: furnace

We bought this old house where the oil furnace worked for a while. Now it does not work even after adding enough oil and priming the furnace. We have already pushed the reset button..so I do not dare to do it again..Would you please tell me what I should do? Thank you very much!

P.S.: The furnace is a Thermopride OL5-85 one.

(Yes this is a duplicate of what I deleted under another name. I just want to have some privacy.)

Answer (score 2):

Call a licensed oil burner service technician (or a company employing such technicians) and have the furnace inspected, then serviced or replaced. Typically your fuel oil supplier is also an employer of service technicians.

Likely normal servicing is all that is required; this is typically performed on an annual basis, rather than waiting until the furnace no longer works.

This really is not a prime area for DIY.